# Sending Laravel Mailable without subject

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm having an odd issue where it's absolutely required I send a mailable without a subject from my Laravel application.

At the moment, this is the `build()` in my mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
    ->view('emails.shipments.remitShipmentFileImages')
    ->subject(null)
    ->attach(storage_path($this->file));
}
```

But I've also tried:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('example@example.com')
    ->view('emails.shipments.remitShipmentFileImages')
    ->subject('')
    ->attach(storage_path($this->file));
}
```

But when I get the email tests I get 'Process Remit Files' in my subject line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the string `Process Remit Files` somewhere in your `remitShipmentFileImages.blade.php` file? I wonder if it's taking a value from that and parsing it into the `subject` line. Could you simply use `->subject("No subject")`?

Comment: @TimLewis - unfortunately not from that file, its completely blank, more of a placeholder file for the time being. And maybe? I’m not entirely sure myself, it was a bit of an odd request but this is what they said: “...and completely blank (no subject or text in the email...” so hence the reason I was trying to force through a blank or null value.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. Beyond those suggestions, I'm not really familiar with the `Mailable` class logic (I tend to just use simple `Mail::send()` calls). And yeah, definitely an odd request.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no subject set the class name ends up being used:

```
protected function buildSubject($message)
{
    if ($this->subject) {
        $message->subject($this->subject);
    } else {
        $message->subject(Str::title(Str::snake(class_basename($this), ' ')));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You can try overriding the `buildSubject` method to remove the fallback for a blank subject:

```
protected function buildSubject($message)
{
    $message->subject($this->subject);

    return $this;
}
```

As long as swift allows a blank subject I would imagine it should be okay.